# Nvidia drivers not functioning on kernel 4.15.0-33-generic

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics, xorg

After updating my system and rebooting, I tried to launch NVIDIA X Server Settings to see if my driver had updated properly. It did not show any Nvidia driver installed, and `sudo lshw -c display` outputted

```
 *-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:28:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
   resources: irq:62 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:c000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
```

I blacklisted nouveau in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:

```
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
```

and updated `initramfs` but `lshw` still showed nouveau after rebooting. I also tried uninstalling `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` but weirdly this did nothing. I also ran `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` but it did not install anything.

I was able to get the proprietary Nvidia drivers running only by booting into kernel 4.15.0-23-generic.  Is it possible to get proprietarry drivers to work on -33?

EDIT: X11 seems to restart when using nouveau and launching certain applications. Tilix, Firefox, Steam, Discord, Nautilus and System Monitor seem to work, but all (tested) settings applications seem to cause the restart. Will update after testing more apps

EDIT 2: More testing showed that only settigns applications seem to cause the restart. This includes Display Preferences, System Settings, Budgie Desktop Settings, but not NVIDIA X Server Settings. I should also add that the restart brings me back to the login menu, not to the desktop.

EDIT 3: I fixed it! I had to reinstall my kernel with `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-4.15.0-33-generic` and `lshw` shows the Nvidia driver in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it! I had to reinstall my kernel with `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-4.15.0-33-generic` and `lshw` shows the Nvidia driver is in use.

Comment: I am the author. I can’t mark my question as “Answered” without an answer, and StackExchange requires me to wait 8 hours before accepting my own answer. Sorry for the confusion.